# Create stored procedure from a dll in sql server 2008 correctly

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, dll

I have a dll created with a code like:

```
public partial class StoredProcedures
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
    public static void STOREDPR(SqlString a1, SqlString a2, SqlDouble a3)
    {
     ....
    }
}
```

so as I need to create the procedure BUT using a .dll of that code...
I was trying

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY test  from 'C:\Documents and Settings\theDLL.dll' WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE
```

till that is perfect, the problem comes when doing...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TEST AS EXTERNAL NAME test.STOREDPR @a1 nvarchar, @a2 nvarchar, @a3 double
```

I can not make it work, can you please correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing the class name **StoredProcedures**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TEST 
  @a1 nvarchar(100), 
  @a2 nvarchar(100), 
  @a3 float 
AS EXTERNAL NAME test.StoredProcedures.STOREDPR
```

Comment: I tried it, but has problem now with the parameters....
`Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure STOREDPR , Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '@a1'.`

Comment: Yes, sorry my answer wasn't right the first time.  I've corrected it.

Comment: @cMinor - Did my answer work for you or is something else not working?